moveit task constructor execution results are inconsistent with the planned results in gazebo
Hello stackoverflow community! Here is my problem:
Environment:
ros2 version: humble
gazebo version: Fortress
Problem Description:
I used MTC(moveit task constructor) to plan and execute a pick place task, and MTC planned an solution. But when I execute the solution, gazebo does not strictly follow the planned order. It did not wait until one subtask was completed before starting the next subtask. Instead, a transition stage seemed to be added between each sub-task, which resulted in each sub-task not being fully executed, ultimately leading to task failure.
For example, theoretically, the robot arm should move to the grasping position（i.e. complete move to pick stage）, then approach object, and then close gripper,as shown in the gif:
plan_outcome_in_rviz
But in actual execution, the robot arm seems to start to approach the object before it reaches the grasping position, and closes the gripper at the same time,as shown in the gif:
execute_outcome_in_gazebo.
Code:
Here is my code to start movegroup and its related settings:
    # Load the robot configuration
    # Typically, you would also have this line in here: .robot_description(file_path=urdf_model_path)
    # Another launch file is launching the robot description.
    moveit_config = (
        MoveItConfigsBuilder("ur10e", package_name=package_name_moveit_config)
        .trajectory_execution(file_path=moveit_controllers_file_path)
        .robot_description_semantic(file_path=srdf_model_path)
        .joint_limits(file_path=joint_limits_file_path)
        .robot_description_kinematics(file_path=kinematics_file_path)
        .planning_pipelines(
            # pipelines=["ompl", "pilz_industrial_motion_planner", "stomp"],
            pipelines=["ompl","pilz_industrial_motion_planner"],
            default_planning_pipeline="ompl"
        )
        .planning_scene_monitor(
            publish_robot_description=False,# True False
            publish_robot_description_semantic=True,
            publish_planning_scene=True,
        )
        .pilz_cartesian_limits(file_path=pilz_cartesian_limits_file_path)
        .to_moveit_configs()
    )

    # Enable the execution of tasks in the MoveIt Task Constructor (MTC).
    move_group_capabilities = {"capabilities": "move_group/ExecuteTaskSolutionCapability"}
        
    # Start the actual move_group node/action server
    start_move_group_node_cmd = Node(
        package="moveit_ros_move_group",
        executable="move_group",
        output="screen",
        parameters=[
            moveit_config.to_dict(),
            {'use_sim_time': use_sim_time},
            {'start_state': {'content': initial_positions_file_path}},
            move_group_capabilities,
        ],
    )

Here is controller manerage config file:
# controller_manager provides the necessary infrastructure to manage multiple controllers efficiently and robustly using ROS 2 Control.
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 10 # update_rate specifies how often (in Hz) the controllers should be updated.

    # The JointTrajectoryController allows you to send joint trajectory commands to a group 
    # of joints on a robot. These commands specify the desired positions for each joint.     
    arm_controller:
      type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController

    grip_controller:
      type: position_controllers/GripperActionController
    
    # Responsible for publishing the current state of the robot's joints to the /joint_states 
    # ROS 2 topic
    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

# Define the parameters for each controller
arm_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - shoulder_pan_joint
      - shoulder_lift_joint
      - elbow_joint
      - wrist_1_joint
      - wrist_2_joint
      - wrist_3_joint

    # The controller will expect position commands as input for each of these joints.
    command_interfaces:
      - position
    
    # Tells the controller that it should expect to receive position data as the state 
    # feedback from the hardware interface,
    state_interfaces:
      - position

    # If true, When set to true, the controller will not use any feedback from the system 
    # (e.g., joint positions, velocities, efforts) to compute the control commands. 
   
    open_loop_control: true

    # When set to true, it allows the controller to integrate the trajectory goals it receives. 
    # This means that if the goal trajectory only specifies positions, the controller will 
    # numerically integrate the positions to compute the velocities and accelerations required 
    # to follow the trajectory.
    
    allow_integration_in_goal_trajectories: true
      

grip_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joint: gripper_joint_1

Terminal warn:
Here are some messeage in terminal:
[moveit_task_constructor_visualization.execute_task_solution]: The trajectory of stage '0' from task '' does not have any controllers specified for trajectory execution. This might lead to unexpected controller selection.

Is it due to this warn?
When I execute individual sub stage step by step, it is able to complete each sub stage, and then finish the pick place task as planned in gazebo.
My Question:

Why are the step-by-step execution results different from the total task execution results?
How to make the total task execution result the same as the planning result, so that the robotic arm can complete the pick place task the same as the plan.


I found the reason:
It is the (virtual) robot controller in Gazebo reports success prematurely, in which case the next stage will be executed before the previous one is correctly finished.
I used joint_trajectory_controller(JTC) provied by ros2_controllers. But I didn't set any constraints for JTC in controllers.yaml, which means there is only default constraint: stopped_velocity_tolerance=0.01.
So once the task execution time planned by MTC is arrived, as long as the joints speeds are less than 0.01rad/s at this time, the controller will report success. Since the "constraints.joints.goal" is not set, the controller will not check whether the actual joint angle reaches near the goal angle.
Besides, the max_velocity and the max_acceleration in joint limits.yaml is set too high, which exceeds the actual joint limits in gazebo, so the joints can't reach goal angle as fast as MTC planned.
Therefore, I did two things to sovle the problem:

Set JTC constraints in controllers.yaml:

Lower the max_velocity and the max_acceleration in joint limits.yaml:


reference:
1.relevant problem
2.JTC setup parameter
3.a copy of this problem in github and detailed answer
